# How to make setInterval() to wait for an interval (like 10 seconds) before EVERY iteration?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The normal behavior of **`setInterval(function() {...}, intervalInMilliseconds)`** in Javascript is such that it is called for the first time after `intervalInMilliseconds` milliseconds, and after that continues to run again and again *without any delay or wait*.

I need my code to be executed after every, say, 10 seconds. The following will execute the function for the first time after 10 seconds and then continue to execute it again and again (until clearInterval() is called) without any delay/wait.

```
setInterval(function() {
    //code, e.g. some AJAX request
}, 10000);
```

I need ***each*** iteration to be executed after a 10 seconds delay. How can I do that?

Comment: `continues to run again and again without any delay or wait.` - well, it continues to run every `intervalInMilliseconds` ... so the code you wrote will run after 10 seconds, then 10 seconds after that, then 10 seconds after that, then 10 seconds after that, then 10 seconds after that, etc

Comment: `and after that continues to run again and again without any delay or wait.` That's not the case... if `setInterval` *blocked* the browser, no one would use it. Your code must be buggy.

Comment: Amm... `setInterval( , 10000)` will execute function every 10 seconds... Your described scenario and code sample is not likely to be related

Comment: The setInterval() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: is your `//code, e.g. some AJAX request` taking close to 10 seconds? did you want the next interval to start 10 seconds after `//code, e.g. some AJAX request` finishes? use `setTimeout` after `//code, e.g. some AJAX request`

Comment: post the complete code. it must be something else causing the issue.

Comment: I doubt there is an issue in the code, it's more likely a lack of understanding of how asynchrony works

Answer (score 2):

So, as I understand it, you want the "loop" to execute 10 seconds **after your code has completed**? If so, you could do something like this...

1. Execute your synchronous long running code
2. Execute another loop, 10 seconds later (I've used 1 second in the example)

**Synchronous example...**

```js
var loop = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    doSyncWork()
    loop()
  }, 1000)
}

loop()
```

**Or asynchronously (e.g. ajax)...**

```js
var loop = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      doAsyncWithCallback(loop)
    }, 1000)
}

loop()
```

**Or with a Promise...**

```js
var loop = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      doAsyncWithPromise().then(loop)
    }, 1000)
}

loop()
```

Comment: `synchronous long running code` ... but the question mentions AJAX ... if "do your work here" includes AJAX that takes a long time to respond, the `loop` call should be done inside the AJAX success callback

Comment: @JaromandaX - yes, good point. I've updated the example to mention `synchronous`, I'll provide an `asynchronous` example as well.

Comment: you could create a generic repeat function for the promise version `var repeat = (fn, delay) => setTimeout(() => fn().then(() => repeat(fn, delay)), delay);` so ... `repeat(doAsyncWithPromise, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

> The normal behavior of setInterval(function() {...},
>   intervalInMilliseconds) in Javascript is such that it is called for
>   the first time after intervalInMilliseconds milliseconds, and after
>   that continues to run again and again without any delay or wait.

thats not true.
mormal behavior of setInterval is to execute callback every `n` milliseconds.
every callback call will occur after previous callback invocation over `n` milliseconds.
take a look

```js
let counts = 0;
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(counts % 2 == 0 ? 'tick' : 'tack');
  counts++;
  if (counts == 5)
  clearInterval(interval);
},1000);
```

> I need each iteration to be executed after a 10 seconds delay. How can
>   I do that?

like this:

```
setInterval(callback, 10000);
```

every callback will be called each ten seconds